# AWS Managed Hyper ledger fabric block chain client.getUserContext is returning null

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I am trying to to create REST Server in windows local for Hyper ledger block chain, When I try to enroll user I am getting error called user not found. Same solution I tried in AWS EC2-instance is working fine but, if I am trying to call chain code in Windows Visual Studio Code editor local, it is not working.

Locally I tried to put breakpoint, then I got `client.getUserContext()` method is returning null error.

I added postman service picture please do check.

Please do help me for this.

[image]

Comment: I am using non profit git solution. And i tried all the steps in AWS EC2-Instance, that was working fine. But now I am trying to setup Rest service in windows localy, which is not working. Here I added connection profile setup and pem file localy and trying. Please let me know, if I did anything wrong here